# How to serialize and deserialize FormCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to serialize a FormCollection object, and based on what I have researched, it inherits NameObjectCollectionBase so it also inherits GetObjectData and ISerializable. Wouldn't this mean it is serializable?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.118).aspx

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

//Serialize
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
  formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
  string test = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
  Session["test"] = test;
};

//Deserialize
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String((string)Session["test"])))
{
  data = (FormCollection) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

I, unfortunately, got this error:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection' in Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral... is not marked as serializable.
```

Because this is a sealed class, I cannot extend it and add the [Serializable] Attribute.

My questions is:

1. Why I can't serialize FormCollection like this?
2. And how I can serialize/deserialize a FormCollection object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It cannot be serialized like this because it lacks `[Serializable]` attribute. That means developers of this class had no intention to make it serializable (with `BinaryFormatter`). The fact it's parent class implements `ISerializable` and marked with `[Serializable]` does not change anything - child class might have it's own internal details which will be lost during serialization if it was allowed to serialize any descendant of serializable class.
2. If you want to use `BinaryFormatter` (which might or might not be the best way) - you can do it like this:

   ```
   BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();            
   //Serialize
   string serialized;
   using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
       // pass FormCollection to constructor of new NameValueCollection
       // that way we kind of convert it to NameValueCollection which is serializable
       // of course we lost any FormCollection-specific details (if there were any)
       formatter.Serialize(stream, new NameValueCollection(data));
       serialized = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());                
   };

   //Deserialize
   using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(serialized))) {
       // deserialize as NameValueCollection then create new 
       // FormCollection from that
       data = new FormCollection((NameValueCollection) formatter.Deserialize(stream));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this cleared a lot of things up! Off the top of your head, can you think of any potential problems BinaryFormatter will have in this example?

Comment: If you are not going to pass serialized data anywhere - I think it is fine to use BinaryFormatter. But note that form collection can in theory contain objects that are not serializable (though it is uncommon).